# How to get Java TCP Server and Client application to loop until a certain number of requests have been made

Tags: java, tcp

I've written both a TCP server and a TCP client application in eclipse. The Client gets user input in the form of a string then sends it to the server who capitalizes it and sends it back. They need to keep looping until the server has received a certain number of requests in which case it closes the connection between he sockets and stops. Unfortunately it only seems to loop once. I will provide a sample output of what I'm talking about after the code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class TCPServer {

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    String clientSentence;
    String capitalizedSentence;
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
    int requests = 0;
    while (true) {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader( connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream (connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        do {

            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
            outToClient.flush();
            requests++;
        }
        while(requests < 10);
        outToClient.writeBytes("REQUEST LIMIT REACHED");

        }

}

}
```

and the client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TCPClient {

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    String sentence;
    String modifiedSentence;
    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //Creates socket, replace the hostnmae/ip address with the ipaddress of the computer running the server application.
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("10.69.88.130", 6789);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    do {
        System.out.print("TO SERVER: ");
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
        outToServer.flush();
        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
    }
    while (!modifiedSentence.equals("REQUEST LIMIT REACHED"));
    System.out.println(modifiedSentence);
    clientSocket.close();
    }

}
```

and finally the output I'm getting

```
TO SERVER: testa
FROM SERVER: TESTA
TO SERVER: testb
(nothing else is displayed after this line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your code is working (kind of). You get a successful run, then you restart your client without restarting the server. Your `request`-value does not reset to 0 and after restarting the client the first request your client does is number 10 for your server.
So why is that request comming through? Because you flush the string first and then check your counter.

I have modified your server a little bit. Maybe that is what you are looking for?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class TCPServer {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        String clientSentence;
        String capitalizedSentence;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
        int requests = 0;
        while (true) {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader( connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream (connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            while (requests < 10) {

                clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
                capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase();
                outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence + " Request: " + requests +  '\n');
                outToClient.flush();
                requests++;
            }
            outToClient.writeBytes("REQUEST LIMIT REACHED");
            requests = 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried integrating your edit with my code, and tried a few changes as well, but it keeps giving the same output.

Comment: It gives you the same output? Even though i changed the output to add the request number? have you tried adding the nummer to your response for debugging purposes?